# Grocery crud in windows hosting

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I have setup Codeigniter on my server and I installed Grocery crud on it. Unfortunately server is windows based and does not support url rewriting and I am stuck using Grocery crud with it.

Can someone explain the solution to this, as I searched grocery crud forum and found nothing.

Regards

Comment: Are you suggesting that the sheer fact that it's a windows based server prevents URL rewriting, or you actually don't have access to configure such URLs?

Comment: Not suggesting instead asking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change config file in CodeIgniter and change 
$config['querystring'] = false

Now you can access GroceryCrud library functions like this
www.example.com/index.php/ControllerClass/FunctionName

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `web.config` in your web root and place the following into the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The above is the example used on the Codeigniter Forums [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/91954).

You may also need to ensure that `$config['uri_protocol']` is set to `AUTO`

Comment: while I never use the above config but I implement a default solution which will work on any hosting service which is change your CI config file and change the querystring parameter to false. 

now you can access the grocery crud lib as www.example.com/index.php/ClassName/functionName

Comment: Ah fair enough. You should either accept an answer or post your own and accept it so this question stops appearing in unanswered lists.